# XMLHttpRequest to php file not returning anything

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I have an XMLHttpRequest That is fired after a button to send a user a friend request im sending two parameters. The first parameter is the profileID and the second parameter is the userID. I have this request going to a page that i want to just echo the profileID back and just give a console.log of the XMLHttpRequest responseText. The issue is when i run the page im getting no errors, the XMLHttpRequest is successfully reaching the PHP document because everything is printing out and changing but just a blank console.log. I will provide a screenshot of the console. I also have the Javascript XMLHttpRequest Code along with the PHP code listed below. I have also tried casting the parameters to a string to see if that might change anything with no luck.

**Javascript XMLHttpRequest Code**

```
        ajax.open('POST', './assets/js/ajax/_sendFriendRequest.php', true);
        ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlendcoded');
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
                document.getElementById('sendFriendRequestButton').disable = false;
                document.getElementById('sendFriendRequestButton').innerHTML = 'Friend Request Sent';
                console.log(ajax.responseText);
            }
        }
        ajax.send("profileID="+_profileID+"&userID="+_userID);
```

**Full Javascript Function**

```
function sendFriendRequest(profileID, userID){

        document.getElementById('sendFriendRequestButton').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('sendFriendRequestButton').innerHTML = '<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>';
        // Create a variable with information passed through
        let _profileID =  profileID;
        let _userID = userID; 
        console.log(typeof _userID);
        console.log(typeof _profileID);
        console.log(_userID);
        console.log(profileID);


        const ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

        ajax.open('POST', './assets/js/ajax/_sendFriendRequest.php', true);
        ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlendcoded');
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
                document.getElementById('sendFriendRequestButton').disable = false;
                document.getElementById('sendFriendRequestButton').innerHTML = 'Friend Request Sent';
                console.log(ajax.responseText);
            }
        }
        ajax.send("profileID="+ _profileID +"&userID=" + _userID);

    }
```

**_sendFriendRequest.php**

```
<?php 

$_profileID = $_POST['profileID'];
echo $_profileID;

?>
```

If you view the screenshot that i have provided you can see that 4 things get console logged. The typeof and the value of the variables being passed through to that function. Right under those though you can see that the console log for the XMLHttpRequest is also being fired with nothing being passed through. I have even tried to just return instead of trying to echo but with no luck still. I have looked through each line and can't seem to find any errors im no professional i havent messed around with any XMLHttpRequests for about a year now. Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

[Screenshot of the console after running the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGaUV.png)

Comment: Typo: `urlendcoded` should be `urlencoded`

Comment: Wow thanks that fixed it can't believe i spent all this time and it was just a typo smh. Thank you once again.

Comment: @Barmar That was good.  I still cannot find it.   688,708 points.   That's impressive.  Good thing you say it's BarMar not BarMan.  Guess what I first saw. Do you actually use jQuery?  If so why?  One more.  Is you profile pic any where recent?

Comment: @Misunderstood The pic is 18 years old, I've lost some hair and gained some grey....

Comment: @Misunderstood I've uploaded a newer picture.

Comment: Okay put the other one back☺

Comment: Looks like the condition `if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200)` was never true, so try and log both of those values without wrapping in any condition.

Comment: It might be time to start using the `fetch` api and let `XMLHttpRequest` fade away?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Im not familiar with that. I will look into that thank you.